# read.sas7bdat adding extra row

Tags: r, import, sas

I am trying to import a SAS dataset into R. 
The code has to be dynamic. SAS is doing some processing and creating a SAS dataset which i want to import in R to continue the process. 
I am using the package `sas7bdat`.
It is working perfectly fine if there are any rows in sas dataset. But if the sas dataset has 0 rows, while importing 1 row is automatically created in R dataframe post import with junk values.

The code i am using is:

```
library("sas7bdat")
a <- read.sas7bdat("C:/path_of_sas_dataset/dataset.sas7bdat")
```

Now if there are any rows in the `dataset.sas7bdat` then the import is proper and successful but if the dataset is empty, R is creating a junk row in "a" dataframe having proper column structure.

Kindly help me to import the dataset successfully.

Comment: For empty SAS dataset, when R read it in with sas7bdat, it produce one raw, columns of numeric are 0, and columns of character are empty. So what is your question?

Comment: Once I import a SAS dataset with 0 rows in R, the dataframe created in R contains 1 row with garbage value(numeric columns have -6.677 as value and character column are null).I wanted the import to result in dataframe with 0 rows(like sas dataset). Is it possible?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of the R package. You could try contacting the author and see if they can modify it to detect that there are no rows in the SAS dataset.  It can detect when there are no columns in the SAS dataset and issues an error.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new and am not aware how I can do that. How should i contact the author and ask him for this?